# Проблемы с созданием колонок в postgressql

Tags: python, база-данных, postgresql, передача-данных

```
lessons.append(each.text)
lesson = each.text
params = [lesson]
cursor.execute('ALTER TABLE lessons ADD COLUMN %s text' % (params))
base.commit()
```

Я получаю ошибку. Проблема в том, что при парсинге сайта я не знаю, понадобится ли мне ещё одна колонка. Тем более я не знаю название будущего столбца. Помогите корректно сфоормулировать механизм подствки данных для postgresql.

Comment: Это похоже на проблему [молотка](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-xy). Вы, похоже, хотите решить задачу храннения разных атрибутов для разных типов объектов. См. https://bit.ly/3vDI4zk или https://bit.ly/3qTYdNq Еще вам может подойти просто `nullable` поле, т.е. поле значение, в котором необязательно. Еще вариант поле типа [json/jsonb](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.htm).

Comment: @Roman Konoval, проблема не в этом. Я уже написал и затестил кривой, но рабочий алгоритм сравнения строк. Это всё будет строками. А проблема с подстановкой решилась сама собой - у меня expect отрабатывал запланированно, как и задумывалось.

Answer (score 0):

Берите

```
cursor.execute('ALTER TABLE lessons ADD COLUMN %s text' % (lesson))
```

И всё ок